# What is sense RNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna

I heard my professor use this term.He said that it is a RNA that has the sense of synthesising the protein. But there's no authentic online source to verify it, except [this](http://www.biology-pages.info/A/AntisenseRNA.html) one (biology-pages.info) which says:

> Messenger RNA (mRNA) is single-stranded. Its sequence of nucleotides is called "sense" because it results in a gene product (protein). Normally, its unpaired nucleotides are "read" by transfer RNA anticodons as the ribosome proceeds to translate the message.

So my question , is mRNA or the pre-mRNA called the sense RNA ?

Comment: I suppose it could be, considering that things like siRNA use "anti-sense" sequences to form double-stranded RNA, targeting it to the degradation pathway, but I've never heard the term before. It's kind of like we hear the term "[disgruntled](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disgruntled)" all the time, but no one is ever described as being "gruntled".

Comment: When I see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisense_RNA) it seems logical to call every mRNA sense RNA.

Answer (score 3):

Both mRNA and pre-mRNA would be considered "sense"

The term "sense" means that the strand is the direct coding strand. That is, the strand that has the proper codons to be translated into the protein of interest. This term can be applied to both DNA and RNA.

The term "anti-sense" means that the strand is Watson-Crick complementary to the "sense" strand. Likewise, the term can be applied to both DNA and RNA.

The "anti-sense" strand of DNA is used as the template to create an RNA transcript that copies the "sense" strand of DNA. Therefore, the mRNA is always "sense" regardless of its stage of maturity.